# Deserialize array of tuple with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit

I am using Retrofit with Gson and I have a Json object likes this:  **"fees":[[0,0.26],[50000,0.24],[100000,0.22]]**
How do I deserialize it into an array of tuple using Gson. Something likes this.

```
public class MyClass{
    public List<MyTuple> Fees;
}

public class MyTuple{
    public int volume;
    public double percentFee;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom Gson Deserializer solves my problem. Here is the code:

```
 GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
 gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(MyTuple.class, new MyTupleDeserializer());
 Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
 MyClass myClass= gson.fromJson(json, MyClass.class);
```

Here is the code for MyTupleDeserializer class

```
 private class MyTupleDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyTuple> {
    @Override
    public MyTuple deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonArray tupleValues= json.getAsJsonArray();
        MyTuple myTuple= new MyTuple();
        myTuple.setVolume(tupleValues.get(0).getAsInt());
        myTuple.setPercentFee(tupleValues.get(1).getAsDouble());
        return myTuple;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First note: It is better if we define `MyClass` like the following. use small 'f' instead of 'F'

```
public MyClass {
 public List<MyTuple> fees;
}
```

The following code can be used to deserialize your string

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyClass myClass = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyClass.class);
```

Comment: Your solution does not work since I have a list of tuple. Each tuple is a 2-elements array of 2 different object type (integer and double). Any idea?

Comment: Did you get any compilation errors? or the data is not deserialized properly?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally learn how to user a custom Gson Deserializer to parse it.